# Using QGIS to count houses on imported OpenStreetMap or Google Maps

Tags: qgis

The QGIS project I'm working on has two base maps imported from the web; Google Maps and OpenStreetMap. Is there a way to designate an area on the map, either using the polygon tool or something else, and then automatically count the buildings within that area on the map?

Comment: base map are usually image (jpg or png) so you wont be able to extract information from them (there are vector tile base map where you may be able the extract the building and even the building type if the information is present but it wont be straightforward and by nature tile cut object so the count wont be accurate). On the other hand openstreetmap data can be easily queried with the overpass turbo wizzard (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to ask only one question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try QuickOSM plug-in for QGIS:

[osm-in-qgis](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm-in-qgis/)

[QuickOSM](https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/user-guide/end-user/)

With the plugin you can download / extract data from OSM to your project as Points / Lines ... and afterwards use it as any other data in your QGIS project.

or

use [google api places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview?hl=en)

> Also, is there a way to differentiate residential buildings/houses
> from commercial buildings/shops?

This is only possible if you find a tag that make this distinction and much more important someone has tagged it.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags

You can predict urban morphology by values as height, area, perimeter and data from OSM etc... but therefore you don't get a plugin, this has to be done by coding.

A Python library could be:

[momepy.org](https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/index.html)